# Rails comma separated search with scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, sqlite

I would like my search to allow for multiple inputs.  I have a scope in my model:

```
scope :by_description, lambda { |description| where('description LIKE ?', "%#{description}%") unless description.nil? }
```

Currently if I search for "abc, efg", it will look for that exact string.  How can I modify my scope to allow "abc, efg" to search for any records that have either "abc" OR "efg" in the description field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this (based on other answers):

```
  scope :by_description, ->(desc=nil) {
    if desc.blank?
      all
    else
      terms = desc.split(/\s*,\s*/).map { |t| t.strip }.map { |t| "%#{t}%" }
      where( ( ["#{table_name}.description like ?"] * terms.count).join(' or '), *terms )
    end
  }
```

Comment: This is correct now after the edits.  The basic concept is to split the string on commas, remove extraneous spaces, and wrap each term in "%".  Then, the where clause is generated based on the number of terms using "or" between each item.  If the passed in description is blank it'll just return "all" but you can make that into whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm unfamiliar with the ->(desc=nil) syntax.  What is that doing exactly?

Comment: The only issue with this is that I'm stringing together a bunch of scopes for each of my search fields, and if I leave the description blank, it throws a no method error saying it cannot find the next scope method.  Any ideas why that would happen?

Comment: Strangly, if I simply delete 'all', everything works fine.  Not sure why that was causing the errors upon blank inputs.

Comment: Probably just need to change it up to do nothing if desc is nil/blank.  As for "->(desc=nil)" it simply causes "desc" to default to "nil" if nothing is passed in.  You might want to get rid of the "=nil" to force a value to be passed in.  You probably want to make your controller check to make sure that the user has actually typed something in the box before doing this search.

Comment: @sabrams ah, sorry. In rails 4 the functionality of `all` changed to return a scopable object. I should pay more attention to the question tags ^^"

Comment: No worries, it's good to know for my next app or whenever I eventually update.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
scope :by_description, lambda { |description|
    description.split(",").
    map(&:strip).
    inject(self) { |memo, term|
        memo.where("description like ?", term)
    }
    unless description.nil?
}
```

What this does:

- takes the incoming string and splits it into an array of comma-separated strings
- calls `strip` on each string to remove leading and trailing spaces
- uses `inject` to chain together a collection of `where` clauses, one for each search term in the array

I haven't actually tried so it may require some adjustment. But the approach is sound. The key bit is that you need multiple `WHERE` clauses to get the "and" behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, so I believe I may have mispoken.  I would like to search for "abc" OR "efg" and find any records that have either of those strings.    Also, it doesn't like that you've got two sets of curly braces and the unless statement.  If I get rid of the unless statement there are no errors, but it throws an error if it's as is.

Comment: A few more questions:  I understand map() but don't understand the &:strip syntax.  I'm also confused about the inject statement.  Is the memo simply the position of the array and the term is the string that resides in that position?  Sorry for all the questions, I just want to make sure I understand all of the code so I'm learning and not just pasting.

Comment: map(&:strip) is the equivalent of map { |s| s.strip }.  It applies the given method to each item in the array.

Comment: If you want `OR` instead of `AND`, the code looks quite a bit different -- you'll have a single `WHERE` clause with a variable number of ?'s (one for each search term), like `where("description like ? or ? or ?", *terms)`. And note the use of the splat operator (*) to turn an array of terms into a list of formal parameters.

Comment: The inject statement *is* confusing. It's a way of chaining together the result of the provided block (memo.where...), called once for each parameter in the array of terms. But if you want `OR` behavior, as you've now indicated, you won't use inject anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is based off Todd's answer:

```
scope :by_description, ->(desc=nil) {
    if desc.present?
        desc.split(",").map(&:strip).inject(self) do |memo, term|
            memo.where("#{table_name}.description LIKE ?", "%#{term}%")
        end
    else
        all # or none, if you want no results returned      
    end
}
```

Logic wise essentially the same, but I used the stabby syntax, and ensured that the scope would always return something chainable. I also like to be safe and add the `table_name` to manually built queries, to prevent ambiguous table errors (when 2 or more tables have a description field).

Comment: I've tried both of the answers and they both run, but give no results regardless of input, and if I leave the input blank, an error is thrown.